# Displaying mjpeg/h264 live streaming (with additional information) on a web page?

Tags: node.js, websocket, video-streaming, h.264, mjpeg

Right now my goal is to grab a streaming video from an IP surveillance camera and display it on a web page.

The camera allows to encode the streaming either in h264 or mjpeg, and transmits it by the RTSP protocol.

The streaming has to be available for several kinds of devices (mainly computers, android smartphones and iphones).

According to my findings it seems like the best option for doing that (in terms of latency) is to transmit the frames of the video through a websocket:
http://phoboslab.org/log/2013/09/html5-live-video-streaming-via-websockets.

Almost all the implementations of this mechanism I've found are based on mjpeg since it's easier to get the video frames. 
There's also a h264 player: https://github.com/131/h264-live-player, based on https://github.com/mbebenita/Broadway, which I didn't manage to run ( I would appreciate any help in that respect).

Now the first question is: it is worth trying to work with h264 (since it saves a lot of bandwidth). Or would the h264 decode process probably introduce too much latency?

I would also like to ask if anyone knows a better solution that the one I'm trying to implement.

Finally, where I say "additional information" I mean that I might want to include some additional data associated with some video frames. (something like subtitles or telemetry data).

Comment: Hi Adriano Todaro, i'll be glad to help you in having your MARVELOUS h264-live-player working, please open a issue on github so i could take a look (new version available, maybe a lot simplier for you to use)